# Overshoot computations not matching

Tags: continuous-signals, linear-systems, step-response

Take the following transfer function of a 3rd order system:

$$H(s)=\dfrac{2.302~s+0.3548}{s^3+0.739~s^2+3.223~s+0.3548}$$

with poles:

```
         Pole              Damping       Frequency      Time Constant  
                                       (rad/seconds)      (seconds)    

 -1.13e-01                 1.00e+00       1.13e-01         8.89e+00    
 -3.13e-01 + 1.75e+00i     1.76e-01       1.78e+00         3.19e+00    
 -3.13e-01 - 1.75e+00i     1.76e-01       1.78e+00         3.19e+00
```

and with the following unitary step response:

[image: unitary step response]

If I compute the [percentage overshoot (PO)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overshoot_(signal)) based on the damping ratio $\zeta=0.176$, I get:

$$PO=100{\times}e^{\dfrac{-\zeta\pi}{\sqrt{1-\zeta^2}}}=100{\times}e^{\dfrac{-0.176\pi}{\sqrt{1-0.176^2}}}=\boxed{57.02\%}$$

However, if I compute the PO using the graphical method (comparing the peak value with the final value) I get a completely different result:

$$PO=\dfrac{v_{peak}-v_{final}}{v_{final}}{\times}100=\dfrac{1.2-1}{1}{\times}100=\boxed{20\%}$$

I don't understand why such discrepancy. Why are my PO computations not matching?

Comment: remember that 3rd-order is not the same as 2nd-order.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson Thank you for the reminder. Do you imply that one of the methods is not suitable for 3rd-order systems?

Comment: read the sources you cite regarding *percentage overshoot*.  what is all of that math, from which you derive a mathematical expression apply to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Computing the [partial fraction expansion](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=partial%20fractions%20of%20(2.302*s%20%2B%200.3548)%20%2F%20(s**3%20%2B%200.739*s**2%20%2B%203.223*s%20%2B%200.3548)),

$$H (s) = \frac{2.302 s + 0.3548}{s^{3} + 0.739 s^{2} + 3.223 s + 0.3548} \approx \frac{2.2861 - 0.0309306 s}{s^2 + 0.626454 s + 3.1525} + \frac{0.0309306}{s + 0.112546}$$

For the time being, let us neglect the step response of the 1st order subsystem. Note that the 2nd order subsystem has the following form

$$\pm \gamma (s - z) \left(\frac{\omega_n^2}{s^2 + 2 \zeta \omega_n s + \omega_n^2}\right)$$

where $\gamma \in \mathbb R$ is the gain (or attenuation) and $z \in \mathbb R$ is a (finite) zero. However, the formula you used to calculate the step response overshoot is only applicable for 2nd order systems of the form

$$G (s) := \frac{\omega_n^2}{s^2 + 2 \zeta \omega_n s + \omega_n^2}$$

whose zeros are at infinity. To summarize, the overshoot is smaller than you expected because:

- you neglected the 1st order subsystem.
- you neglected the attenuation $\gamma \neq 1$.
- you did not subtract $\gamma$ times the derivative of the step response of $G (s)$ at the peak time.

In any case, *not* neglecting the above would only provide one **estimate** of the overshoot. To compute a satisfactory approximation of its exact value, you can take the inverse Laplace transform, differentiate and find where the derivative vanishes.

Comment: You are absolutely right. Thank you for your enlightening answer!